# How to implement pybind11 with buffer protocol for non trivial (POD) class

Tags: c++, pybind11

I've just learned about `Python Buffer Protocol` and I would like to leverage it to create python `numpy` arrays from `C++` raw data. I can either use pybind11 or c++ python lib directly, but no other binding generator =/

Reading [pybind11 docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#buffer-protocol) and experimenting with it, it seems we can easily generate python bindings with buffer protocol from trivial C++ structures (e.g. `std::vector<int>` or a `struct` with plain old data types such as `int`, `float`, etc). However, adding buffer protocol to more complex structures is not possible or not well documented. For my use case, I would be to pybind a `std::vector<struct Sequence>`, with `Sequence` being defined as follows:

```
struct Sequence {
    std::vector<float> feature;
    std::vector<int> label;
}
```

Once the python bindings with buffer protocol are implemented on C++ side, on Python side I could do

```
for seq in vector_sequence:
   feature_data=numpy.array(seq.feature, copy=False)`
   label_data=numpy.array(seq.label, copy=False)`.
```

In the loop above, `vector_sequence` is an opaque binding for the C++ `std::vector<Sequence>` and `seq` is a `Sequence` that holds the two vectors that I want to use as input for `numpy` arrays without copying data from C++ to Python.

Does anyone know whether this is supported by pybind11 or c++ python lib?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working! I learned that I don't have to implement protocol buffer for `Sequence` class if I want to prevent copy of `feature` and `label` members, not the actual `Sequence` class as a whole.
Example:

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<Sequence>);

py::bind_vector<std::vector<int>>(m, "VectorInt", py::buffer_protocol());
py::bind_vector<std::vector<float>>(m, "VectorFloat", py::buffer_protocol());

py::class_<SequenceReader>(m, "SequenceReader").def("read_sequences", &SequenceReader::read_sequences, py::return_value_policy::take_ownership);
```

Important to notice that I am using `pybind11/numpy.h` and `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE` to prevent copies